# Angularjs Nested ng-repeat with expression used in filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use a value from the first ng-repeat in a filter in the nested ng-repeat.

Specifically `{{alpha.value}}`. This renders fine in the first repeat, note the filter and the `h3` tag.

However the expression renders as text in the second repeat, again not the filter, and thus the repeat is empty as it doesn't match. I feel like I am missing something incredibly obvious. Any thoughts? Thanks

```
<div ng-repeat="alpha in alphabet" ng-hide="(tlds | filter: {group: '.{{alpha.value}}'}).length<1" ng-cloak="cloak">
    <h3>{{alpha.value}}</h3>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="tld in tlds | filter: {group: '.{{alpha.value}}'} | filter: {name: query} | orderBy: 'name'" ng-cloak="cloak">
            <a href="/downloads/pdftld/{{tld.pdf}}" target="_blank">{{tld.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle with it broken http://jsfiddle.net/eminentstyle/v5g4u948/2/

If I manually insert the intended expression result, line 20 filter: `{group: '.c'}`, you can see the intended result for the first section http://jsfiddle.net/eminentstyle/kwmj5mtu/2/

Comment: Could you please provide a working Plnkr or JSFiddle?

Comment: I have edited my question with failing and a non dynamic working example.

Comment: I think you have complecated a lot your example.Plese tell us what is the last result you expected. for example.Do you mean that you want to show for all aplahabet only groups that contains a tld inside in our example you last result is c -> .com com . Provide a table with your expected result plz

Comment: And exactly what do you expect the search field to do?

Comment: I do agree my example is complicated, there is probably a much simpler solution to what I am after. The search is also causing confusion.... let me update them to better reflect what I am after. As an aside, the search was just a filter, narrowing down what ultimately will be a VERY long list of tlds.

Comment: I have updated the fiddles to hopefully demonstrate what i am trying to achieve. Ultimately there will be divs that are only only displayed if there are tlds to display. This is the 'parent' ng-repeat. The child ng-repeat is for the actual tlds, the list items. I want to filter those based on a value from the parent repeat. `{{alpha.value}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/v5g4u948/3/

```
<div class="container" ng-app="Tlds">
    <div class="page-header">
         <h1>Tlds</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type='search' class='form-control' placeholder='Search' ng-model='query' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="TldsCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="alpha in alphabet" ng-hide="(tlds | filter: {group: '{{alpha.value}}'} | filter: {name: query}).length<1" ng-cloak="cloak">
                 <h3>{{alpha.value}}</h3>

                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="tld in tlds | filter: {group: alpha.value} | filter: {name: query} | orderBy: 'name'" ng-cloak="cloak"> <a href="/downloads/pdftld/{{tld.pdf}}" target="_blank">{{tld.name}}</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Be carefull `filter: {group: '.{{alpha.value}}'` means to filter all group that **contains** alpha.value. For example . 'ie' matches with 'e'.

Comment: Bingo, it was incredibly simple... I was confusing how to display my expressions in filters. Oh thanks very much!